# Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions (Without fragments inside fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let me preface this post by saying that Ive searched about this issue a ton and found no answer that are targeted to my problem. Other questions about this involve Fragments inside Fragments, but that is not the case for me.

My setup is very simple. `Activity` hosts a `ViewPager` that uses a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with numerous fragments that are the same type.

This crash seems to be exclusive to **Android 5.1.1**.

Im using the support library for Fragments and call `getSupportFragmentManager()` for use with the adapter. The fragments display some views inside a `RecyclerView`.

Heres the full crash log for those interested:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {workout.progression.lite/workout.progression.lite.ui.PerformanceTargetActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4852) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4870) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:197) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1735) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Activity)
```

I dont perform anything in `onPause` except for unregistrering a `Bus` (Otto).

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

              // use below code will like U
    //        if(info.constellation.trim().equals("")) {
    //            tv_age.setText(info.age);
    //        } else {
    //            tv_age.setText(info.age + "  " + info.constellation);
    //        }

            // should be like this, no if()...else
            tv_age.setText(info.age + "  " + info.constellation);
}
```